# Azure API App multiple actions with same verb and different routes gives swagger error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, azure-api-apps

I have a ApiController with those GETs:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult GetUsers()
    {
        [...]
    }

    public IHttpActionResult GetUsers(guid ID)
    {
        [...]
    }

    [Route("api/Users/{CodeA}/{CodeB}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUsers(string CodeA, string CodeB)
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

The routing in webapiconfig.cs is the standard one:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional}
);
```

Trying to use swaggerUI I get a 500 error, and by fiddler I get:

*Not supported by Swagger 2.0: Multiple operations with path 'api/utenti' and method 'GET'. See the config setting - \"ResolveConflictingActions\" for a potential workaround"*

If I remove the last GET method swagger parses the api correctly. I've read from many sources that the problem is solved by specifying a different route, and I've tried to achieve this by adding the *Route* attribute to the last action.

Can someone please point me out in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding Route attributes to all of your action methods and your controller?

Comment: Yes, but the results are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code worked for me:

```
[Route("users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUsers()
    {
        string test = "";
        return Ok(test);
    }
    [Route("{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUsers(Guid id)
    {
        string test = "";
        return Ok(test);
    }

    [Route("{CodeA}/{CodeB}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUsers(string CodeA, string CodeB)
    {
        string test = "";
        return Ok(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but I get the same multiple get error as before

Comment: I set this up as follows: a new blank web API project, installed the swashbuckle swagger for web API from nuget, and created a controller with the above code. I used visual studio 2013 and web API 2. I also added an index.html file and set that as the start page. If you duplicate my set up, do you still get the error?

Comment: I'm actually using VS2015, and the project is created starting from "Azure Mobile App" Template, wich should be pretty much the same as a WebAPI project with 2 example controllers in addition. In VS2015 I can't find the option to use an empty WebAPI template. I don't have VS2013 installed so I can't replicate your test.

Comment: This time I used VS2015, created a new ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework), used the Empty Template and included Web Api references, created the controller with above code, created an index.html page, and installed the latest stable release of swashbuckle. Swagger worked fine. I then tried using the mobile template with swagger, and it looks like a bunch of configuration of swagger is required (it did not run). I do not have time to play with this more right now.

Comment: Perhaps, you can replicate my latest setup with VS2015 and web api only and test whether your routing/controller are actually the source of the problem?

Comment: Yes! your last setup was working, so I confronted it with mine, and found out that I was only missing **config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();** in the _webapiconfig.cs_  Register method. Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: No problem. Glad to hear that you were able to solve it.